# How to update iOS 14 Widget background color from the app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

For my widget, I want users to be able to select a widget background color of their choice, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to do this with a `ColorPicker` and `@AppStorage`

```
ColorPicker("Background Color", selection: Binding(get: {
                    bgColor
                }, set: { newValue in
                    backgroundColor = self.updateColorInAppStorage(color: newValue)
                    bgColor = newValue
                }))
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                .font(.headline)
```

backgroundColor is an `@AppStorage` variable that holds the RGB values

In my Widget extension class, I am using this variable to set the widget background color in the @main struct:

```
@main
struct MyWidget: Widget {
    @AppStorage("backgroundColor", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.MyWidget")) var backgroundColor = ""
    @State private var bgColor = Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
    let kind: String = "Count"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            SubscriberCountEntryView(entry: entry)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(bgColor)
                .onAppear {
                    if (backgroundColor != "") {
                        let rgbArray = backgroundColor.components(separatedBy: ",")
                        if let red = Double(rgbArray[0]), let green = Double(rgbArray[1]), let blue = Double(rgbArray[2]), let alpha = Double(rgbArray[3]) {
                            bgColor = Color(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: alpha)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Count")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium])
    }
}
```

This only seems to be working when the app is first installed on the device. After that, no matter how many times I choose a color and update the widget, the background color won't change. If I delete and install the app again, the color changes.

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are accessing UserDefaults in your Widget rather than in the widget's timeline provider. You are also storing your Color in an unnecessarily complicated way.

Here is a simple example that shows you how to save a UIColor into UserDefaults and access it in your widget. Although you are using Color, Color structs can be created from a UIColor. However `ColorPicker` allows you to create a binding with a `CGColor` or `Color`, and `CGColor` can be converted easily to `UIColor`.

## ContentView

In my ContentView I have created a simple app that uses a ColorPicker with a binding of `CGColor`. When the color is selected we pass it as a UIColor to the save function. This uses `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert the UIColor into Data, which can easily be saved into UserDefaults. I use `AppStorage` to store the Data created from the UIColor.

We then call `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` to make sure that the WidgetCenter knows that we want to update the widgets.

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct ContentView: View {

    @AppStorage("color", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app.identifier"))
    var colorData: Data = Data()

    @State private var bgColor: CGColor = UIColor.systemBackground.cgColor

    var body: some View {

        ColorPicker("Color", selection: Binding(get: {
            bgColor
        }, set: { newValue in
            save(color: UIColor(cgColor: newValue))
            bgColor = newValue
        }))
    }

    func save(color: UIColor) {
        do {
            colorData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        } catch let error {
            print("error color key data not saved \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

### MyWidget

Next in the Provider we use property wrapper `AppStorage` to access the Data that we saved for the color. We do not access `AppStorage` inside `MyWidgetEntryView` or inside `MyWidget` as it will not work there.

Inside my provider I have created a computed property that gets the UIColor from the color data that we stored in `AppStorage`. This color is then passed to each entry when it is created. This is key to using `AppStorage` with your widgets, the values must be passed when the entry is created.

MyWidgetEntryView is very simple it just shows the date that it was created and the background color.

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {

    @AppStorage("color", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app.identifier"))
    var colorData: Data = Data()

    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(color: color)
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(color: color)
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(color: color)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }

    var color: UIColor {

        var color: UIColor?

        do {
            color = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData)
        } catch let error {
            print("color error \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
        return color ?? .systemBlue
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date = Date()
    let color: UIColor
}

struct MyWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(entry.color)
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)
        }
   }
}

@main
struct MyWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MyWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            MyWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

Here it is working

[image: Widget with color picker]

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. One suggestion though, dragging across the color picker causes the save function to be called hundreds of times, unnecessarily reloading the widget. So instead, I setup a notification center publisher to check when the app moves to background, then reload the widget.

Comment: You could also use `.onReceive`, with an ObservableObject tracking the chosen color, and adding a debounce to it limiting the number of times the save function is called. That would require a little more setup but it would remove the need to send a notification. There are many options that you can use to reduce the number of calls that are made.

Comment: @Andrew: Does this also work on mac os widgets?
Could you publish the repository?

Comment: @Paul I haven’t tried it on macOS. What repository are you talking about?

Comment: Just in case the code won't work for you.. 
Remember to add the App Groups Capability to both the app target and the widget extension.